Accordion based on details and summary animated with JavaScript doesn't work as expected in the Chrome Browser
Here is an accordion whose 'details' elements are opened and closed using 'maxHeight'. The expand/collapse animation is done by CSS.


document.querySelectorAll('summary').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const details = event.target.parentElement;
  const onAnimationEnd = cb => details.addEventListener(
    "animationend", cb, {
      once: true
    }
  );
  details.classList.add('expand');
  if (details.open) {
    event.preventDefault();
    details.classList.add('collapse');
    onAnimationEnd(() => {
      details.classList.remove('expand', 'collapse');
      details.removeAttribute("open");
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      details.dispatchEvent(new Event('animationend'));
    }, 500);
  }
}));
details {
  max-height: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
}

details>p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

summary {
  min-height: 2rem;
  border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.expand {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 10rem;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-out;
}

.collapse {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 2rem;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-out;
}
<details name="learn-css">
  <summary>Accordion Summary 1</summary>
  <p>Accordion Content 1</p>
</details>
<details name="learn-css">
  <summary>Accordion Summary 2</summary>
  <p>Accordion Content 2</p>
</details>
<details name="learn-css">
  <summary>Accordion Summary 3</summary>
  <p>Accordion Content 3</p>
</details>
<div>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>



This code works as expected in the Firefox browser, but not in the Chrome browser. If one 'details' element is open and I click on another closed 'details' element to open it, the already open 'details' element closes automatically because the 'open' attribute is removed from this 'details' element. Actually, the 'open' attribute should remain on this 'details' element. The CSS animation then no longer works for this 'details' element because the CSS class 'expand' has not been removed. I thought that maybe the event bubbling was responsible for this and used 'stopPropagation'. But that didn't help.
Normally, the automatic closing of an open 'details' element when clicking on another closed 'details' element must be programmed separately. In my case, the automatic closing is an unwanted side effect in the Chrome browser.

@CBroe
Okay, now I've changed the CSS so that I don't have to fire the onanimationend event manually:
    details {
      max-height: 2rem;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #eee;
    }

    details[open] {
      max-height: 10rem;
    }
    
    details > p {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    summary {
      min-height: 2rem;
      border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    .expand {
      animation-name: expand-height;
      animation-duration: .5s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .collapse {
      animation-name: collapse-height;
      animation-duration: .5s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      overflow: hidden;     
    }

    @keyframes expand-height {
      0% {
        max-height: 2rem;
      }
      100% {
        max-height: 10rem;
      }
    }

    @keyframes collapse-height {
      0% {
        max-height: 10rem;
      }
      100% {
        max-height: 2rem;
      }
    }

Here is the modified JavaScript code:
    document.querySelectorAll('summary').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      const details = event.target.parentElement;
      const onAnimationEnd = cb => details.addEventListener(
        "animationend", cb, { once: true }
      );
      details.classList.add('expand');

      if (details.open) {
        event.preventDefault();
        details.classList.add('collapse');
        onAnimationEnd(() => {
          details.classList.remove('expand', 'collapse');
          details.removeAttribute("open");
        });
      }
    }
    ));

The HTML code is the same:
  <details name="learn-css">
    <summary>Accordion Summary 1</summary>
    <p>Accordion Content 1</p>
  </details>
  <details name="learn-css">
    <summary>Accordion Summary 2</summary>
    <p>Accordion Content 2</p>
  </details>
  <details name="learn-css">
    <summary>Accordion Summary 3</summary>
    <p>Accordion Content 3</p>
  </details>
  <div>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

However, this does not answer my question: Why does the accordion not work as expected in the Chrome browser?

I can achieve a small improvement by removing the CSS class "expand" at the end of the "expand" animation:
    document.querySelectorAll('summary').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      const details = event.target.parentElement;
      const onAnimationEnd = cb => details.addEventListener(
        "animationend", cb, { once: true }
      );
      details.classList.add('expand');
      onAnimationEnd(() => {
        details.classList.remove('expand');
      });

      if (details.open) {
        event.preventDefault();
        details.classList.add('collapse');
        onAnimationEnd(() => {
          details.classList.remove('collapse');
          details.removeAttribute("open");
        });
      }
    }
    ));

Then the "expand" animation is at least executed correctly, even if the "details" element has previously closed automatically.
But the actual problem with the Chrome browser remains.

Dispatching an animationend event yourself via a timeout, kinda defeats the purpose, doesn't it? Guess you tried that as a workaround, because animationend did not want to fire by itself? That would be because you are not animating the max-height, you are transitioning it - so that would fire a transitionend event then.

From MDN:

The name attribute specifies a group name — give multiple  elements the same name value to group them. Only one of the grouped  elements can be open at a time — opening one will cause another to close. If multiple grouped  elements are given the open attribute, only the first one in the source order will be rendered open.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#name
Removing the name attribute from your original markup achieves the behaviour you're after.


document.querySelectorAll('summary').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const details = event.target.parentElement;
  const onAnimationEnd = cb => details.addEventListener(
    "animationend", cb, {
      once: true
    }
  );
  details.classList.add('expand');
  if (details.open) {
    event.preventDefault();
    details.classList.add('collapse');
    onAnimationEnd(() => {
      details.classList.remove('expand', 'collapse');
      details.removeAttribute("open");
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      details.dispatchEvent(new Event('animationend'));
    }, 500);
  }
}));
details {
  max-height: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
}

details>p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

summary {
  min-height: 2rem;
  border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.expand {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 10rem;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-out;
}

.collapse {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 2rem;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-out;
}
<details>
  <summary>Accordion Summary 1</summary>
  <p>Accordion Content 1</p>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Accordion Summary 2</summary>
  <p>Accordion Content 2</p>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Accordion Summary 3</summary>
  <p>Accordion Content 3</p>
</details>
<div>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>




That is not the point. If I remove the 'name' attribute, the previously opened details tag is not automatically closed as soon as another details tag is opened. This means that the desired functionality is no longer available. I was concerned with the following: JavaScript should prevent the abrupt and premature closing of the 'open' attribute of an open details tag as soon as another details tag is opened. This is the only way that the close animation of the open details tag can be played correctly.
